# Mount -a on reboot after modifying /etc/fstab

Tags: unix, filesystems, mount, fstab, temporary-files

I added the third line to /etc/fstab.

```
proc  /proc       proc    defaults                   0     0
none  /dev/pts    devpts  rw                         0     0
tmpfs /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults,noexec,nosuid     0     0
```

Then I run `mount -a` to mount it.  The problem is that when I reboot, I again have to run `mount -a`.  Is there another file I should be editing to make these changes permanent, or have `mount -a` run automatically?

In case it matter, I'm running on a VPS on MediaTemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find your Linux distributions `$ cat /etc/*-release`

for RH based you can

- add your modify `/etc/rc.local` (add `mount -a` in the end of file)
- Run "gnome-session-properties" (GUI) and add your mount to startup

for Debian based

- modify `/etc/xdg/autostart` (add your `mount -a` in the end of file)
- Run "gnome-session-properties" (GUI) and add your mount to startup

for more information you can google `<ditro name> start up <script | application>`

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am running Ubuntu 11.04.  It has both `/etc/xdg/autostart`and `/etc/rc.local`.  Some googling made me think I should use the rc.local. Is one preferred?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the way to go.  `mount -a` should be called during the boot process already.  I suspect that either the tmpfs module or the `dev/shm` isn't available yet when it is called.

Comment: @AlexisK i think rc.local is perfered. PS this script is executed at the end of each `multiuser` runlevel.

Comment: @Bram Thanks for the info.  I did have to modify the tmpfs to get some packages to install correctly.  Can you expand a little bit about why tempfs module would be ready at boot.

Comment: @Alexis-k: I suspect this because the mount appears to fail during boot but is successful afterwards.  If I look at one of our RHEL6 systems I see that the tmpfs filesystem is mounted in `/etc/rc.sysinit`, a `grep -r tmpfs /etc/*` should show you if this is configured on your system as well or not.  The relevant mount commands are after the various sections that set up devices and after the startup of udev.